# BufferedWriter throwing NullOutputStream on write

Tags: java, tomcat

I create a new ProcessBuilder as:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Xmx1G", "-classpath", "<path_to_class>", "<class_name>");

pb.directory(new File(<insert_directory>));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.environment().put("PATH","<env_path>");

Process p = pb.start();
```

Downstream a bit, I run:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exect(<command>);
BufferedWriter input=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader output=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader error=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

input.write(<string>);
```

I can write to the output and error `BufferedReader`s. But I keep getting `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` on `ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write`

Other solutions have suggested getting rid of `.redirectIO()`, but I'm not using that here.

I can comment out the failing input section and the rest of the code executes as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you're using `ProcessBuilder` **and** `Runtime.exec()`? Why are you showing the first code, since that process `p` is entirely different from the process in your "Downstream bit"?

Comment: Well inside of class passed into the `ProcessBuilder`, I run the second `Process p`. So its just a bit of the stack trace.

Comment: So your Java program is running a another Java program which runs another program (is that a Java program too)?

Comment: Potentially. Its a very old java project that im trying to debug.

Comment: If you use ProcessBuilder / Runtime.exec you must consume the stdout/err streams generated by the sub-process simultaneously. The way you have it where "A runs B which runs C" needs these consumers running: A reading stdout (ok in current thread), and B reading stdout+stderr (not ok in same thread). Also if the amount you wish to write to stdin is large, writing to stdin of sub-process should also be on separate thread to those stdout/err reader threads.

Comment: @DuncG okay, I think i follow. Do you have a suggestion on how this could be fixed from my code snippet?

Comment: Whats really throwing me is the fact that this project apparently worked fine before being ported to a new server. Once running on the new server, it wasnt working. Which makes me think the code is fine?

Comment: The code is probably not fine, it probably was dependent on the old server somehow and doesn't have proper error checking. Is the process started correctly, or do you just assume it is and start trying to give it input?

Comment: Your error message includes `NullOutputStream` which suggests that there is some other step you've omitted from this question as that class is used to deliberately discard stdin for the subprocess.